# React Native exported Dimension height and width are small

Tags: react-native

In my app I have a `style.js` file where I am exporting styles to my components. I have a container style that I want to always be 100% of the width and height.

```
import { StyleSheet, Dimensions } from 'react-native';

const { height, width } = Dimensions.get('window');

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    height,
    width,
  },
};

export default styles;
```

When I import this object into my component the height and width are much smaller than the width of the screen. If I get the height and width within the screen component's js file, the dimensions are correct.

Is there a way to get the `height` and `width` once and export them to all my screen components or do I have to get the `Dimensions` from every screen individually?

Comment: What are the values you get for {height, width} when getting them that way? Are they always the same? Does this affect iOS, Android, or both?

Answer (score 1):

You could use flex:1 instead. flex:1 ensures that this component will take up the existing space that is available. Your component is kinda container and it's common behaviour to use flex:1.

Comment: Using `flex:1` does not work for me. It ends up narrower and shorter. I'm using native-base and react-navigation. I think all of their wrapper components (Root, Container, Content, AppNavigator) are causing this.